# Access nested Json response with Guzzle Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle

I make a request by Guzzle in Laravel and receive a response like this:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "ErrorDescription": "Success.",
    "Data": [
        {
            "brand_id": 1,
            "tenant_id": "tn001",
            "brand_name": "ABC",
            "brand_url": "url.com",
            "brand_avatar": "avatar.com",
            "brand_banner": "banner.com",
            "brand_about": "abc."
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can access to the brand_name field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = json_decode($guzzleResponse,true);

echo $response['Data'][0]['brand_name'];
```

You just have to decode the json ton an array and parse it as usual.
Just mind the nested array inside the `Data`.